# Append content of field to title field in Wagtail-CMS-admin

Tags: wagtail

In order to differentiate pages in Wagtail CMS admin (in a page listing view, not in the edit page view), the `title` is - in my case - not enough. I have a long list of pages of one page-type (say `class BlogPage`), and some of these pages could have the same `title`. So I would like to add a second identifying field (here: `date_from`, a `DateField`) to this title.

I thought of

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    ...
    def title(self):
    if self.date_from:
        return self.date_from + " - " + self.title
    else:
        return self.title
```

but this does not work, the `page.title` without my `def` is used for the corresponding [Wagtail-admin-template](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailadmin/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/listing/_page_title_explore.html).

Short version: How to pre/-append an existing field to the title in Wagtail-admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wagtailmodeladmin](https://github.com/ababic/wagtailmodeladmin) seems to do exactly what I've searched for: extending the wagtailadmin to display a defined set of fields - not only `title` - on a page model basis; like I would have it in the Django admin site.

This way I do not alter the default wagtailadmin page listing - like I've tried it in my question, but `hook` in an additional page listing as an extra wagtail-sidebar-navigation-entry.

Thanks to an [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31832305/5071435) I stumbled upon this possiblity.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to replace the title across all of the model admin (Yes, this includes the Edit page), Wagtail has a built in [mechanism](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/model_reference.html?highlight=get_admin_display_title()#wagtail.wagtailcore.models.Page.get_admin_display_title) for that.

```
def get_admin_display_title(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.date_from, super().get_admin_display_title())
```

Answer (score 0):

`title` is an actual Django model attribute, don't try to override it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted

The actual admin template from wagtailadmin/pages/list.html generates the list of pages in a loop using `{% for page in pages %}` and calls `{{ page.title}}` via an include (`templates/wagtailadmin/pages/listing/_page_title_explore.html`) extensively throughout. So based on inspecting the code, there is no support for this in Wagtail itself. Check the other includes `templates/wagtailadmin/pages/listing/*`.

However, Django supports overriding one app's templates with your own. You can copy this template into your project's template folder, keeping the same path (e.g., `templates/wagtailadmin/pages/listing/_page_title_explore.html` assuming your project is set up with a templates directory).

You'll have to replace the calls to `page.title` with your own version. A filter or tag might make this easier. Add the following filter to your templatetags (e.g. `myapp/templatetetags/myapp_tags.py`):

```
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def uniquify_title(page):
    specific_page = page.specific
    try:
        return specific_page.date_from.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " - " + specific_page.title
    except AttributeError:
        return specific_page.title
```

And then replace usages of `{{ page.title}}` in the template starting around line 7 and 9 with:

```
{{ page|uniquify_title }}
```

---

The downside of this is you have to update your own version of `list.html` every time Wagtail is updated. You could try submitting an issue on Github and proposing a fork which supplies an "admin_title" callable or something like that.

Comment: In order to not fire on each and every template, this could be "narrowed" to a specific template: `@register.filter
def uniquify_title(page):
    specific_page = page.specific
    if specific_page.template == 'foo/bar_page.html':
        try:
            return specific_page.datum.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "  –  " + specific_page.title
        except AttributeError:
            return specific_page.title
    else:
        return specific_page.title`

Comment: I don't get why Wagtail doesn't simply use __str__(self) to display a page's name in the admin.